# Unit testing event handlers in IE

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, event-handling, tdd, automated-tests

Part of my application prevents the default action on an event only under certain circumstances. I'm working strictly TDD, and so I need to test that the default event is being prevented at the right time. This is easy in most modern browsers, as `dispatchEvent` et al will trigger both my event handler and the default, and I can test if the default event (hash change) has happened. IEs fireEvent doesn't do that though... It only triggers my handler, so there's no way to test if it's done as it should without a manual click happening somewhere.

My event handler isn't exposed, and even if it was, testing if it returned false would be a bit too close to testing the implementation. Is there a textbook way for handling this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript executed in a web page by a browser is sandboxed and has no access to things such as the [native event queue](http://www.bolinfest.com/javascript/web-application-testing.php).  Use native [IE Automation Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9683/Automating-Internet-Explorer) to fit your needs or as part of a package such as [Internet Explorer Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) as a complete solution.